# Grouping the elements of a list together by different number of pairs each time

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, grouping

I have the following question to ask.
I have a list of bs4.element.Tags like [[tag1, tag2, tag3], [tag4, tag5], [tag6], [tag7, tag8, tag9, tag10]]. So each sub list contains names of actors from different movies. So the first sub-list has three actors, the second two actors and so on.

What I do is to remove the bs4.element.Tag by calling the function .text per element of each sub-list. Then I append the result to a new list which is like: [str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10]. Although this is not my desirable result. I want the actors in the new list to be grouped as in the original list.

So the desirable result should be: [[str1, str2, str3], [str4, str5], [str6], [str7, str8, str9, str10]]
Where str = string name of each actor.

Do you know how can I achieve this?

**My example** (follow the pictures):

[list of bs4.element.tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhZqo.png)

[list of actor names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qes.png)

Comment: try: [[t.text() for t in small_list] for small_list in big_list]

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Or I mixed up the small_list with the big_list. In my description which is the big list (as you write in your code)?

Comment: big_list is the original list of lists, small list is actually just a name you could use anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do list comprehension as suggested by @Ezer K. But I personally prefer the map function.

```
actor_list = []
for tags in tag_list:
    actor_list.append(list(map(lambda x: x.text, tags)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as I have written my tag_list is a list of different lists like  [[<a href="/name/nm1503403/"> Shane Carruth </a>, <a href="/name/nm1503383/"> David Sullivan </a>, <a href="/name/nm1503463/"> Casey Gooden </a>], [<a href="/name/nm0881420/"> Anand Upadhyaya </a>, <a href="/name/nm1503468/"> Carrie Crawford </a>].

Comment: Just as you mentioned, I'm iterating over each item of the main list and passing that item which is also a list to the map function which consequently applies the .text() method to each element using the lambda function. I'm then appending the entire list to the actor_list.

So the final actor_list would be:

[['Shane Caruth', 'David Sullivan', 'Casey Gooden'], ['Anand Upadhyaya', 'Carrie Crawford]]

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to do completely without seeing your code, but you're going to want to iterate through your element tags, pull out the content from each element into a list, then append that into a final list. So something like:

```
final_list = []
for tag in tags_list:
    actors = tag.find_all('a')
    actors_list = [ x.text.strip() for x in actors ]
    final_list.append(actors_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is actually what I do in my code. Although I should also iterate over each sub list. Because in your code "tag" is a list of bs4.elements. So "tag.find_all('a')" gives me an error: "
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all' ".

Comment: my tag_list seems like this: [[<a href="/name/nm1503403/"> Shane Carruth
</a>, <a href="/name/nm1503383/"> David Sullivan
</a>, <a href="/name/nm1503463/"> Casey Gooden
</a>], [<a href="/name/nm0881420/"> Anand Upadhyaya
</a>, <a href="/name/nm1503468/"> Carrie Crawford
</a>]...So if i write tag_list[tag] is a list and not an element...this is why i get the error